# how to swap records having unique constraint in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have 2 tables user and userinfo. userinfo table contains user_id(id of user table) column which has UNIQUE constraint.
now i have 2users(primaryUser and secondaryUser) which has records in user and userInfo tables.

The primaryInfo object contains primaryUserId and secondaryInfo object contains secondaryUserId

I want to swap the userinfo data of primaryUser to secondaryUser and viceversa. I am doing like this

```
primaryInfo.setUserId(secondaryUser.getId());                       
secondaryInfo.setUserId(primaryUser.getId());

session.update(primaryInfo);
session.update(secondaryInfo);
```

but when commiting the transaction it is giving error like
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:147 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_infos_unique_user"
  Detail: Key (ui_user_id)=(52560087) already exists.

can you please tell how to do this.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DEFERRABLE and INITIALLY DEFERRED properties on the constraint and update both records in a single transaction.   DEFERRED means the constraint will not be evaluated until the transaction is commited -- at which time it should be valid again.

However: I have not figured out how to use Hibernate annotations to specify the DEFERRED properties, so you will have to use LiquiBase to maintain the database schema (not a bad idea anyway.)  (Or use "raw" SQL which is not so good an idea.)

[See this question for more about the annotations (alas I cannot use LiquiBase on the project I ask about there.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317706/can-an-initially-deferred-constraint-be-defined-using-a-hibernate-annotation)

Comment: without being able to annotate it in hibernate, this solution does not work for integration tests that are using an h2 database or similar...

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle database you can create next unique constraint with special attributes '**DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED**':

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (table_field) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Answer (score -2):

A possible trick to work around the unique constraint is to do 3 updates:

1. update row A with a value for the column that no other row can use. `NULL` may be used if not forbidden by a not-NULL constraint, otherwise `0` if not forbidden and assuming it's an integer, otherwise a negative value.
2. then update row B with its final value (the previous value from row A)
3. then update row A with its real final value (the previous value from row B)

Comment: getting the same problem after following the above process.. here i am using the same session for updating the userinfo and getting the error at the time of transaction commit.

Comment: If I commit the transaction after every session update, then it is working fine. but commiting the transaction after all the updates, it is giving error.

Comment: @user1169474: I'm afraid it doesn't make sense to me. The above method should work regardless of when commit occurs since the unique constraint is never violated, in any of the 3 steps.

Comment: In addition to the above, if the unique constraint is deferred at commit time as it seems to be, it shouldn't have a problem in the first place with the simple swap method mentioned in the question. That's precisely the point of a deferred constraint.

Answer (score -3):

As error Shows:
there is a unique constraint on userInfo table. that means user must be unique. So If you wnat to swipe the two user Id. you have to perform following steps 
 1. Remove the constraint 
 2. Swap two id's(same code as you currently have) 
 3. Add Constaint.

Comment: The id shown in the error is the primaryuserId and I dont want to remove the Unique constraint.

Comment: I don't think this solution is practical at all. When are you going to do that in a real app.